# Il significato di "fiducia" nella politica o nel decreto?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning

**Ho incontrato queste frasi in un articolo di un giornale:**

> - Lega, Fratelli d'Italia e Forza Italia si preparano a votare 'no' al decreto 'Cura Italia', su cui sarà posta la questione di fiducia.
> - La scelta del governo di mettere la fiducia è una scelta divisiva...

**La traduzione di Google:**

- Lega, Fratelli d'Italia and Forza Italia are preparing to vote 'no' to the decree 'Cura Italia', on which the question of trust will be placed.
- The government's choice to put trust is a divisive choice ...

**Cosa significa 'fiducia' in questo contesto? Si tratta di una procedura legislativa? L'opposizione vota 'no' vuol dire che non si fida del decreto 'Cura Italia' o non si fida del governo? Il risultato del voto può influire sulla conversione del decreto?**

Comment: In questo caso la traduzione corretta di fiducia non è "trust" ma "confidence" (come in ["vote of no confidence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_of_no_confidence))

Comment: Questa non sarebbe una domanda di italiano ma di politica / educazione civica: il punto è sapere cos'è una "questione di fiducia" nell'ordinamento italiano (e quella pagina di Wikipedia inglese non lo spiega adeguatamente, secondo me). Questa pagina di Wikipedia italiana mi sembra che sia una spiegazione migliore: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Questione_di_fiducia .

Comment: Si tratta delle accezioni numero 2 del [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fiducia) e numero 6 del GDLI ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000953.jpg)] e [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000954.jpg)]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per *fiducia* o meglio *[questione di fiducia](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Questione_di_fiducia)* si intende:

> In Italia la questione di fiducia è un istituto della forma di governo
> parlamentare riservato al Governo, non previsto in Costituzione, ma
> disciplinato dai regolamenti interni della Camera e, in modo più
> succinto, del Senato nonché dalla legge n. 400/1988.

Il suo funzionamento è il seguente:

> Il governo pone la questione di fiducia su una legge (o più
> comunemente su un emendamento ad una legge), qualificando tale atto
> come fondamentale della propria azione politica e facendo dipendere
> dalla sua approvazione la propria permanenza in carica. Nella pratica
> politica tale strumento viene usato dal Governo per compattare la
> maggioranza parlamentare che lo sostiene o per evitare l'ostruzionismo
> dell'opposizione.
>
> Ponendo la fiducia sulla legge, tutti gli
> emendamenti decadono e la legge deve essere votata così come è stata
> presentata; sempre più spesso, tuttavia, essa è posta dal Governo su
> un proprio maxi-emendamento. Nel caso in cui il Parlamento respinga
> la questione di fiducia posta dal Governo, quest'ultimo è considerato
> privo della fiducia della Camera/Senato e pertanto è tenuto a
> rassegnare il mandato nelle mani del Capo dello Stato. Va inoltre
> ricordato che tale istituto giuridico richiede modalità garantite
> (voto nominale dell'atto nella sua interezza ed entro 24 ore),
> permette un'attività senza ostruzione, mira ad annullare i franchi
> tiratori che si nascondono dietro il voto segreto e permette una
> veloce espletazione del processo di legiferazione.

Quando c’è urgenza di emanare un decreto legge il governo pone la fiducia mettendo fine alle discussioni in parlamento, che molte volte hanno intento meramente dilatorio. Inoltre il testo viene “blindato” nel senso che non può essere modificato.

Chiaramente se il governo non ottenesse la fiducia su questo provvedimento o anche su altri più importanti, come ad esempio la legge finanziaria, esso potrebbe cadere.

In questo caso se il Presidente della Repubblica prendesse atto che non ci fosse possibilità di avere un nuovo governo sostenuto dalla maggioranza dei parlamentari, scioglierebbe le camere e si andrebbe verso nuove elezioni.

Su Treccani per [fiducia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fiducia/) si può leggere:

> 2. In diritto costituzionale, *voto di f.*, votazione mediante la quale il parlamento approva (o, se la votazione dà risultato negativo,
>    disapprova) gli indirizzi politici e la corrispondente azione del
>    governo; *mozione di f.*, la proposta, fatta da una delle Camere, di
>    ricorrere al voto di fiducia; *questione di f.*, richiesta da parte del
>    governo di ricorrere al voto di fiducia per l’approvazione o la
>    reiezione di emendamenti e articoli di progetti di legge: *il governo
>    ha deciso di porre la questione di fiducia*.